# Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use react-data-grid ([http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/index.html](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/index.html#)) but I keep getting the error:

```
invariant.js:17 Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded.
```

I have tried uninstalling the package and reinstalling to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
render() {
    ...
    var _rows = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            _rows.push({
                id: i,
                title: 'Title ' + i,
                count: i * 1000
            });
        }

        var rowGetter = function(i){
            return _rows[i];
        };

        const columns = [
            {
                key: 'id',
                name: 'ID'
            },
            {
                key: 'title',
                name: 'Title'
            },
            {
                key: 'count',
                name: 'Count'
            }
        ]
   return (
        ...
<ReactDataGrid
                                columns={columns}
                                rowGetter={rowGetter}
                                rowsCount={_rows.length}
                                minHeight={277} />
...
   )
}
```

How can I fix this?

---

I altered my config.js:

```
...
"npm:react-data-grid@0.14.42": {
      "classnames": "npm:classnames@1.2.2",
      "es5-shim": "npm:es5-shim@4.5.8",
      "fbjs": "npm:fbjs@0.6.1",
      "object-assign": "npm:object-assign@2.1.1",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      //"react": "npm:react@0.14.8",
      "react-contextmenu": "npm:react-contextmenu@1.5.0",
      //"react-dom": "npm:react-dom@0.14.8",
      "ron-react-autocomplete": "npm:ron-react-autocomplete@3.0.1"
    },
...
```

And now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or you have multiple copies of React loaded.

Every time I got this error it was because I had react loaded twice, make sure you only load React once, especially if you're using webpack

Comment: Thanks, see my edit. But I now get: Warning: Row: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.